# RTCMulticonnection not working with Firebase

Tags: firebase, rtcmulticonnection

I'm setting up a one-to-one video chat using [RTCMultiConnection](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection). How to use firebase as a signaling server?

I have installed rtcmulticonnection and opened the [Video Conferencing using Firebase demo](https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/demos/Firebase-Demo.html) and then applied this step [here](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/blob/master/docs/api.md#setcustomsockethandler), but it did not work, only one video is showing even if I joined the room, and the chat textbox is not enabled, however, no errors are showing, and I have tried to log a message inside `connection.open` but it is not showing.

I want to apply this [one-to-one video chat](https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/demos/One-to-One.html) but with firebase as a signaling server.

Comment: I have made a lot of researches, I was even debugging the rtcmulticonnection api but couldn't solve this issue. I don't want to use socket.io, I want to use firebase as the signaling server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Custom signaling works only with v3.4.6

Found here: https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/tree/724ead7cbb589a772b8bb41abd22acff3f700a5d/dist

**UPDATE**

Muaz khan is not supporting firebase anymore, here is his reply on my email on **5/16/2019 7:45 AM**:

> Sorry. Actually I'm no-more supporting the firebase.
>
> Their server isn't free and I can't add demos that requires paid servers.
>
> You can install socket.io on heroku which is totally free and works better for >me. You can setup Google' app engine's appspot.com domain as well.
>
> Regards

However, I am satisfied with the current version - v3.4.6, it has all that I need.

I have made some minor fixes to this version, concerning `connection.extra` and `connection.channel` to make it work in different javascript files, but sorry I could not paste the code here because it is big.